# Unknown Encoding: Seeking For Correct Decoding Algorithm That Results in Human-Readable Words

Tags: python, encoding, base64, ascii, decoding

I’m currently stuck at identifying an encoding, that produces text like the following examples:

```
ZEtRGWn*b!ZU
```

```
dT(!MZ*F-
```

```
b#8KXX>Mg?
```

Does anyone have an idea of what that encoding could be?

Thanks in advance!

I already tried to decode these strings on websites like https://dencode.com/ and http://fbcs.bplaced.net/multi_encoder_decoder.html.
Unfortunately, none of them gave me reasonable results.

I expect the decoded strings to be human readable, english words or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: The encoding was base85. Unfortunately, not all of the available base85-Decoders were able to decode the strings.
In the end, I did it with basecrack, a python package for cracking various base encodings.

You can find out more about that here:

- https://github.com/mufeedvh/basecrack#installation
- http://basecrack-web.me/

Comment: There is no way I'd trust a package called "basecrack".

Comment: @MarkRansom You mean, because "crack" is the wrong term?

Comment: or do you just not trust it's results?

Comment: "Crack" is a term you usually see associated with breaking into something, like a safe.